# Java Make Own System.out

Tags: java, jtextarea, printwriter, system.out

Is there any way to make my own System.out? I want to have a class "MyConsole" with an attribute out (PrintWriter) and send from all classes txt messages that will be printed in a JTextArea (like System.out print all messages in the console) without make a instance of it in all classes or pass it in the attributes

Comment: Not as a static reference without doing some really bad design.

Comment: If you really have to, create your own `PrintWriter`, then use `System.setOut(myPrintWriter)`, so that every output to the console will be redirected to your printwriter.

Comment: i want to have multiple "System.out" to link more consoles

Comment: @SorinGeorgeBudescu Create as many `PrintWriter`s you need, set one as output stream with `System.setOut(myPrintWriter)` and use it to propagate the output to the others.

Comment: i need something like ex: Console1.out.println(message1) and the message 1 goes only in the JTextArea linked Console1,  Console2.out.println(message2) and the message 2 goes only in the JTextArea linked Console2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a static final class and static methods and use it through out the application. Static method can be directly called without instantiating the class.

Comment: can i link the jtextarea from my JFrame in a static final class?

Answer (score 2):

> i need something like ex: Console1.out.println(message1) and the message 1 goes only in the JTextArea linked Console1, Console2.out.println(message2) and the message 2 goes only in the JTextArea linked Console2

Why don't you just make your own class that extends `JTextArea` and write a method to do what you want? Something like:

```
public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {
    public void println() {
        //add text to the textarea
    }
}
```

If you don't need your method to have name `println` you can just use the `append` method, which already exists in the `JTextArea`:

```
textArea.append(myString+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this open source Message Console in java.  It's simple to use.

[message console Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253933/message-console-java)